# Duration in ScaleModifier andengine

Tags: andengine

I want to scale an image before screen resume in AndEngine so I have applied the following code to my sprite:

```
ScaleModifier scaleDrag1 = new ScaleModifier(1, 1, 0.7f);

drag1.registerEntityModifier(scaleDrag1);
```

But my issue is that the scaled image is shown when the screen resumes because of the 1 duration. It makes my sprite scale after the screen resume so the scaling is visible to the user, I tried setting the duration to 0 but then that sprite is not shown.

Can anyone tell me what should I do to scale image before resume in AndEngine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casting is required in that case , i resolved with code below :

```
ScaleModifier scaleDrag1 = new ScaleModifier((float) 0.01, 1, 0.7f);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can scale the sprite by using drag1.setScale(0.7f).